# How do you find a javascript variable in the Chrome Dev Tools Heap Profiler?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am playing with Chrome's Dev Tools and its Heap Profiler.  I can't quite figure out how to find the variables defined in javascript on the page.  There's a TON of fascinating stuff you can see, but searching or navigating through it is a challenge.  For example, if you have a tiny script in the body of the page that just has "var x = 42;", how do you find it in the Heap Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

42 is not a heap object. The reason of that is performance and memory. If an integer fits into 31 bit (one bit is reserved for the marker pointer/non-pointer) then v8 stores it as is, otherwise v8 allocates a heap object for it. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWhMKalEicY

So, in your case v8 reserves a slot in context, "associate" the name to the slot and stores 42 into the slot. In case of double, string, array or an object v8 will store pointer to it into the slot. Heap profiler scans heap for the heap objects. After that it scans the content of each heap objects for a pointers to the other objects. As a result it gets the heap graph. Thereby the heap graph doesn't contain plain integers.